# Database requires duplicate values as primary key ( Which is not allowed )?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have a database assignment where I must build the following database.

[image]

The issue is, I am given a table to create called `dependent` which has 5 columns. 1 of these columns is `dependent_name`. It can't be a Foreign Key because there is not table for the dependents, so I assume it is suppose to be a Primary Key.

When I attempted to add the data in the table I was given an error that says I `cannot have duplicate values for primary key`.

Of course this is because you cannot have duplicate primary keys ( Alice is a duplicate value in this situation ), but I am not sure how to get around this. I guess I could make another table called `dependent_info` and make the `dependent_name` and FK, but this is not stated in the instructions from the teacher.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: **dependent_name** seems to have name which can't be unique so Why you are planning to set as primary key.

Comment: Why are you making 'dependent_name'  as primary key. Name can be duplicated. Primary key always remain unique then you have to select that column as primary key which can't be duplicate in any way. As you have already a primary key 'essn'. And if you don't have any foreign key for 'department_name' then why are you giving 'department_name' as primary key.

Comment: perhaps you mean to make (essn,dependent_name) the primary key?  but I would have a separate dependent_id as the primary key; it's entirely possible for a person to have multiple dependents with the same name (or multiple dependents who have not yet been named)

Comment: Okay so to answers everyone's concerns ; I went ahead and simply made another database table that simply has a list of names as primary keys and I am now referencing the names as FK in my table. It makes no sense to have a primary key duplicated and I am pretty positive that the instructor meant for us to do this or simply not list the duplicate, because I do not see how else to go about this other than maybe @ysth response where I make the key the (essn,dependent_name). Should I stick with my solution or ysth's solution of 2 column key ?

Comment: adding another table and putting a name id in your dependent table doesn't buy you anything, just makes things like changing a dependent name much more complicated.  but that really has nothing to do with what the primary key for dependent is??

Comment: The picture in your question is given to you, right? In that case, the primary keys are marked by being underlined (this is a standard notation for keys), and "dependent" therefore has a composite key made of 2 columns. I don't think you are tasked to make any changes to those tables, just literally translate them to ddl statements (if building the database is your task). The only place where you may want to think for more than 0.0000001s is to identify the foreign key relations (the refering column is not necessarily part of a primary key/underlined, the referenced column will be)